# Hybrid Spring Application: Queue consumer and Http, how to run java -jar with different modes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, queue, amazon-sqs

I have an spring app, with two types of beans:

QueueConsumers
RequestMappings

At runtime I would like to spawn two Dockers containers, **with same .JAR**:

Container One: Just to serve HTTP calls
Container Two: Just to consume the queues.

I don't want to waste CPU instantiating tomcat or controller beans, in case it's the instance of queue's consumer

What would be the best way to structure this?
Example to run app with modes:

```
java -jar -Dmode=queue app.jar
java -jar -Dmode=http app.jar
```

My http controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/status")
public class StatusController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getStatus() {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

My sqs consumer:

```
@Service
public class MyQueue {
    @SqsListener("myQueue")
    public void update(@Payload String message) throws ServiceException {
        // Some action
    }
}
```

I arrived at this bean configuration, but I don't know how to "filter" the correct beans or remove tomcat:

```
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mode", havingValue = "queue")
    public static class QueueModeConfiguration {
        public QueueModeConfiguration() {
            System.out.println("QUEUE MODE!");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mode", havingValue = "http")
    public static class HttpModeConfiguration {
        public HttpModeConfiguration() {
            System.out.println("HTTP MODE!");
        }
    }
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly     "com.mysql:mysql-connector-j"
    implementation  "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation  "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation  "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation  "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    implementation  "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs:3.0.1"
}
```